# Silverlight 4: Trademark Symbol

Tags: silverlight, silverlight-4.0, symbols, textblock

I would like to know how to insert trademark symbol in Silverlight via textblock.

I used this `<Run Text="&#0153"/>`  however it appears box only.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not just use the literal character:

```
<Run Text="™"/>
```